# PHP Mailer + MySql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

Olá,

Tenho uma página para corrigir que executa 2 funções a partir do preenchimento de um formulário:
1- manda informações do form para o banco MySql - funcionando ok
2 E_mail de confirmação com os dados preenchidos no formulário. aqui está o problema.

esta parte do código está feita em mail() e preciso da autenticação do PHPMailer para ela, mas não tenho experiência com esta ferramenta e estou perdido na execução desta tarefa. agradeceria a colaboração de vocês para solucionar o problema.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include 'admin/conecta.php';    

    $evento = addslashes($_POST['evento']);


    $sql_eventos = "SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE eve_id = '".$evento."'";
    $consulta_eventos = mysql_query($sql_eventos,$db) or die(mysql_error());
    $qtd_eventos = mysql_num_rows($consulta_eventos);

    while($item_temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta_eventos)){
        $eventos_array[] = $item_temp;
    }   

    $codigo = addslashes(strtoupper($_POST['codigo']));

    $nome = addslashes($_POST['nome']);
    $qtd_adultos = addslashes($_POST['qtd_adultos']);
    $qtd_criancas = addslashes($_POST['qtd_criancas']);
    $ddd_fones = addslashes($_POST['ddd_fones']);
    $fones = addslashes($_POST['fones']);
    $emails = addslashes($_POST['emails']);
    $msg = addslashes($_POST['msg']);   
    $data  = date("d/m/Y - G:i");           

    if (!$nome || $evento == '0' || !$fones || !$codigo) {
        echo "<script> window.alert('Por favor, preencha TODOS os campos marcados com asterisco!'); </script>";
        echo "<script> window.location = 'javascript:history.go(-1)'; </script>";
        die();
    }
    if($codigo != $eventos_array[0]['eve_codigo']){
        echo "<script> window.alert('O codigo no convite individual foi digitado errado!'); </script>";
        echo "<script> window.location = 'javascript:history.go(-1)'; </script>";
        die();
    }
    if (strlen($qtd_adultos) == 0 || strlen($qtd_criancas) == 0) {
        echo "<script> window.alert('Por favor, informe a quantidade de ADULTOS e de CRIANCAS!'); </script>";
        echo "<script> window.location = 'javascript:history.go(-1)'; </script>";
        die();
    }
    $qtd_adultos = (int)$qtd_adultos;
    $qtd_criancas = (int)$qtd_criancas;

    if(!is_int($qtd_adultos)){
        echo "<script> window.alert('Por favor, informe um valor numérico no campo QUANTIDADE DE ADULTOS!'); </script>";
        echo "<script> window.location = 'javascript:history.go(-1)'; </script>";
        die();
    }
    if(!is_int($qtd_criancas)){
        echo "<script> window.alert('Por favor, informe um valor numérico no campo QUANTIDADE DE CRIANÇAS!'); </script>";
        echo "<script> window.location = 'javascript:history.go(-1)'; </script>";
        die();
    }
    if($atv == '2'){$atv = '0';}
        $sql = "INSERT INTO rsvp (rsvp_eve_id, rsvp_con_nome, rsvp_adultos_conf, rsvp_criancas_conf, rsvp_fones, rsvp_emails, rsvp_msg, rsvp_codigo_eve) 
        VALUES ('$evento', '$nome', '$qtd_adultos', '$qtd_criancas', '$fones', '$emails', '$msg', '$codigo')";

    mysql_query($sql,$db) or die(mysql_error());

    $sql_email_noivos = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE cli_id = '".$eventos_array[0]['eve_cli_id']."'";
    $consulta_email_noivos = mysql_query($sql_email_noivos,$db) or die(mysql_error());
    $qtd_email_noivos = mysql_num_rows($consulta_email_noivos);

    while($item_temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta_email_noivos)){
         $email_noivos_array[] = $item_temp;
    }   

    if($email_noivos_array[0]['cli_recebe'] == '1'){
        if(strlen($msg) > 0){
            $ass = 'RSVP - Confirmação de presença';    
            $conteudo = $nome.' também confirmou presença no seu evento. E escreveu "' .$msg. '" Att. Assessoria de Eventos';
        }else{
            $ass = 'RSVP - Confirmação de presença';    
            $conteudo = $nome.' também confirmou presença no seu evento. Att. Assessoria de Eventos';
        }

        if(strlen($email_noivos_array[0]['cli_emails'])>0){
            mail($email_noivos_array[0]['cli_emails'], $ass, $conteudo);
            mail('email', $ass, $conteudo);
        }
        if(strlen($email_noivos_array[0]['cli_emails2'])>0){
            mail($email_noivos_array[0]['cli_emails2'], $ass, $conteudo);
        }                   
    }
    echo "<script> window.alert('Confirmado com sucesso! Obrigado!'); </script>";
    echo "<script> window.location = 'rsvp.php'; </script>";        
?>
```

Caso alguma parte não tenha ficado clara, estou  disponível para exlpicações.

Comment: Lucas, o que você ja tentou?  seu código não contem a classe phpmailer. existem exemplos fáceis na documentação, tente aplicar algum.https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Se eu fosse você, nesse caso, não usaria PHPMailer, mas vai de pessoa e tudo que você precisa saber está no link que o @GabrielRodrigues citou